# Python Program should run multiple times, but only runs once

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, debugging, while-loop

my task is to write a program that repeatedly prompts a user for integer numbers until the user enters 'done'. Once 'done' is entered, print out the largest and smallest of the numbers. If the user enters anything other than a valid number catch it with a try/except and put out an appropriate message and ignore the number. When I run my program it does not repeatedly ask for number, it just does it one time without responding.

```
    try:
        float(num)
    except:
        "invalid input"

    if num > largest:
        largest = num
    
    if smallest == 0:
        smallest= num
    
    if smallest > num:
        smallest = num
    print(num)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do something repeatedly, you need to use a loop - this can either be a for loop or while loop.

In this case, a while loop is best as you want to do a task until you tell it to stop.

```
while True:
    try:
        float(num)
    except:
        continue

    if num > largest:
        largest = num
    
    if smallest == 0:
        smallest= num
    
    if smallest > num:
        smallest = num
    print(num)
    break
```

Notice the `continue` and `break` keywords. `continue` tells the interpreter to skip the rest of the content in this loop, and start again, and `break` tells it to exit the loop and continue the program